# MySQL query to print name and salary of each employee

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this schema:

```
Emp(eid: integer,ename: string,age: integer,salary: real)
Works(eid:integer,did: integer,pct_time: integer)
Dept(did:integer,budget: real,managerid:integer)
```

and I'm trying to print the name and salary of each employee whose salary exceeds the budget of every department that he or she works in.

I have this SQL statement but it returns an empty column for `ename` and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

```
select E.ename, E.Salary
from Emp E
where E.salary > all (select D.budget
    from Dept D, Works W
    where E.eid = W.eid and D.did = W.did)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a normal join

```
SELECT E.ename
FROM Emp E
JOIN Works W ON E.eid = W.eid
JOIN Dept D ON D.did = W.did
WHERE E.salary > D.budget
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I did not think of that!